# Interesting Examples of Using SEMs

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, social-science

Inspired by [this article](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/12/what-love-it-depends-which-language-you-speak) using structural equation modelling (SEM) to investigate inter-cultural conceptions of love, I'm curious:

**What are some interesting, clever, and/or innovative uses of SEMs in the health, life, and social sciences?**

Comment: The Mplus user guide and website (statmodel.com) have lots of interesting examples.

Comment: Yes, @Jeremy, in fact the [Mplus Examples](http://statmodel.com/examples/index.shtml) section of that site has many examples. Thanks